# Implement GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener in Ionic 2

Tags: google-maps, angular, ionic2

I am looking for the syntax to implement GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener with my Ionic 2/Angular 2 app. I would like to redirect to a new page, i.e. push a new page to the the stack on the NavController, when the user clicks the info window inside of google maps.

I have been able to set up the Markers using the following code:

```
    //Creates the event listener for clicking the marker and places the marker on the map 
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, markerCount) {       
      return function() {        
        infowindow.setContent(htmlMarkupForInfoWindow); 
        infowindow.open(this.map, marker); 
      } 
    })(marker, this.markerCount));
```

Unfortunately, the function calls inside the content of the info window lose reference to 'this' which results in errors. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This might be clunky but it appears to work... Posted the whole method for reference. Most of the code is based on an example provided by Josh Morony (https://www.joshmorony.com/)

This allows me to call a function locally passing in the location associated to the infoWindow. The content of the infoWindow is wrapped in a div with a class name 'content'.

```
addMarkerToMap(location, htmlMarkupForInfoWindow){ 
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude); 
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
      position: myLatLng, 
      map: this.map, 
      icon: this.mapIcon,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    }); 

    //Gives each marker an Id for the on click 
    this.markerCount++; 
    this.infoWindows.push(infowindow);

    let self = this;

    //Creates the event listener for clicking the marker and places the marker on the map 
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', ((marker, markerCount) => {       
      return () => {   
        self.hideAllInfoWindows();      
        infowindow.setContent(htmlMarkupForInfoWindow); 
        infowindow.open(this.map, marker); 
      } 
    })(marker, this.markerCount));      

    // add listener that will capture the click event of the infoWindow
    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', () => {
      document.getElementById('content').addEventListener('click', () => {
        self.onLocationSelected(location);
      }, false);
    }); 
  }
```

Feel free to comment if anyone has an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Change inner functions to use `Arrow function` which help you to make `this` available inside function.

```
//Creates the event listener for clicking the marker and places the marker on the map 
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', ((marker, markerCount) => {       
  return () => {        
    infowindow.setContent(htmlMarkupForInfoWindow); 
    infowindow.open(this.map, marker); 
  } 
})(marker, this.markerCount));
```

Comment: Appreciate the tip but this doesn't address the original question. I'm looking for an example of implementing OnInfoWindowClickListener, or whatever event the info window fires. The code I quoted was to show that I was able to tie into the marker click event but have not had success capturing someone clicking on the info window that opens.